# Change query file path in microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, filepath

I am working with Access 2003 and I need to change the filepath for a Query. I am working on a database that I did not create and basically my workflow is using Excel to populate a list (file names and info about photos)
Then I go back to Access and in Query's I have an option for "Append Results" which will update my database with my new information that has been loaded into Excel.

I get an error saying that the filepath is wrong. I know the correct filepath and this is a correct error, I just can't find where to update the query so I can change the filepath. I did a couple of googles and used microsoft help but figured it might be faster to ask in here.

Thank you,

JWV

Comment: @JMK it's in the Queries tab. I know my filepath is incorrect. I work for a large company and our IT department shifted everything around so our shared drives were once on the I: Drive but now are on H:. This is causing the error. Basically I just need to tell the query to search for H:something/something instead of I:Something/something

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the workbook is linked to Access as a linked table. Sort your objects by type, and try and open each linked table until one fails. Then drop the link, and re-create it to the correct spreadsheet with the same table name.

To do this, you first backup the *.mdb (in case you get it wrong) and then just delete the link, like you would delete a table. Next you need to right Click on any table => Import Spreadsheet => Go to your spreadsheet and untick the box that says 'Import into database' (or something similar, I don't have access to Access (ha!) at the minute to test), this will give you a link to the spreadsheet, as opposed to actually copying it as a table, then rename it so it is the same name as the original link.

I guess as an alternative you could remap the drives so that, on machines where this needs to run, the old I: drive is mapped back to I:, and the same for H:.

Comment: How do I drop the link (I'm new to access)

Comment: Also link back-end Access tables using the UNC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention#Uniform_Naming_Convention and not a drive letter (like \\MyServerShare\Accounting\Data\ and not H:\Accounting\Data)

Comment: +1 to @DanMetheus' suggestion, also I agree with your recent thought!